# Angular2+ Angular Google Maps - Configure Map Clusters, Calculator and Options

Tags: angular, google-maps, markerclusterer, angular-google-maps, agm

I need help to implement MarkerCluster with a calculator function. Basically I need to group some markers in a cluster, and use a Calculator to dynamically show images and text in each Marker.

Actually my map works, I show the Markers and some Clusters, but I cant configure `MapOptions` to determine the minimum size of a cluster, and I can't get my calculator function to configure the images according to my values.

To represent my actual situation and what I need, please see this image: https://ibb.co/cqkG8S

The image thats replace the original markers image is divided by 2 squares, the first (green) is a count of elements, the second (blue or red) represents the elements with problems (the cluster with problems show red square).

In the same image, I have the original markers of google thats not replaced by my images. In this case, I believe the ClusterOptions is not configured.

So my problems is:

1. How to use the Calculator
2. How to set ClustersOptions

Thanks for any help!

My code:

1. My Map Declaration (map.component.html):

   <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
   <agm-marker-cluster [styles]="clusterStyles" >
   <agm-marker *ngFor="let marker of markers" [latitude]="marker.latitude" [longitude]="marker.longitude">
2. The important parts of my component (map.component.ts)

   export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

   ```
    @Input('markers') markers: MapMarker[];

    clusterStyles: ClusterStyle[];
    clusterOptions: ClusterOptions;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.clusterStyles = [
            {
                textColor: "#FFFFFF",
                url: "assets/markers/marker1.png",
                height: 36,
                width: 58
            },
            {
                textColor: "#FFFFFF",
                url: "assets/markers/marker2.png",
                height: 36,
                width: 58
            }
        ];

        this.clusterOptions = {
            gridSize: 60,
            minimumClusterSize: 2,
            averageCenter: true
        }
    }

    //Calculate Function - to show image em formatted text
    calculateFunction(markers: MapMarker[], numStyle: number){

        let index: number = 0
        let title: string = "";
        let text: string = "<div style=\"position: relative; top: -4px; text-align: center; margin: 0px auto; width: 60px;\"> <div style=\"display: inline-block; width: 29px;\">{{ELEMENTS}}</div><div style=\"display: inline-block; width: 29px;\">{PROBLEMS}</div></div>";
        let qtdNodes: number = 0;
        let qtdEvents: number = 0;

        for(let i of markers){
            qtdNodes += i.qtdEvents;
            qtdEvents += i.qtdEvents;
        }

        index = (qtdEvents == 0) ? 1 : 2;

        text = text.replace( "{ELEMENTS}", qtdNodes.toString() );
        text = text.replace( "{PROBLEMS}", qtdEvents.toString() );

        return {
            text: text,
            index: index,
            title: title
        }
    }
   ```

   }

Versions

angular - 5.2.6
agm core - 1.0.0-beta.2
agm js-marker-clusterer - 1.0.0-beta.2

Comment: Did you find an answer that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you need to configure your `agm-marker-cluster` instances.

To utilize your calculator function, as [documented here](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/markerclusterer/directives/agmmarkercluster#info), you specify the `calculator` property:

```
    <agm-marker-cluster [calculator]="calculateFunction">
```

And to set your minimum size of a cluster, use the `minimumClusterSize` property.

So that would give you a component invocation like this:

```
    <agm-marker-cluster 
        [calculator]="calculateFunction"
        [minimumClusterSize]="clusterOptions.minimumClusterSize"
        [styles]="clusterStyles">
      <agm-marker>
        ...
      </agm-marker>
    </agm-marker-cluster>
```

Finally, in your `calculateFunction`, you handle the incoming parameters correctly, but you can leave off the `title` in your return object. So you can just return like this:

```
        ... 

        return {
            text: text,
            index: index,
        }
```

Hope that's helpful!

It's been a while since you posted, so perhaps you already figured this out, but I'm adding this answer nonetheless in case others come looking for how to configure this.